# Two vectors linearly dependent on a third vector?

Tags: vectors

I know how to check if a vector or a matrix is linearly dependent or independent , but how do I apply it on this problem?

Let V1 , V2 , V3 be vectors
How do I prove that the vector V3 = ( 2, 5, -5) is linearly dependent on V1 = ( 1,-2,3) and V2 = (4,1,1) ?

Will it be enough or correct if I solved the equation:
α1*V1 + α2*V2 - V3 = 0
and proved it has a solution?

Comment: A side note: 3 vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ are linearly dependent iff they are coplanar

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you can approach with basic methodology:

Consider the equation $c_1(1,-2,3)+c_2(4,1,1)=(2,5,-5).$ Then you will have system of linear equations:

$c_1+4c_2=2, -2c_1+c_2=5, 3c_1+c_2=-5$.

Finding that whether $v_3$ is linearly dependent on $v_1$ and $v_2$ is equivalent to finding the solution of the above system.

A trivial computation shows that

$c_1=-2, c_2=1.$

Thus, the vector $v_3$ is linearly dependent on $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work.

Or you can check that$$\begin{vmatrix}2&1&4\\5&-2&1\\-5&3&1\end{vmatrix}=0.$$It follows from this that there are numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\alpha v_3+\beta v_1+\gamma v_2=0$. If $\alpha=0$, then $v_1$ and $v_2$ would be linearly dependent, and therefore one of them would be the other one times a scalar. But that's clearly not the case. So, $\alpha\ne0$ and therefore$$v_3=-\frac\beta\alpha v_1-\frac\gamma\alpha v_2.$$